# Make spaces show as spaces in minibuffer instead of completion

Tags: minibuffer, whitespace, mapping

The default mapping of `SPC` in minibuffer is `(self-insert-command N)`. However, I prefer `SPC` to simply type a single space (for instance, in passing arguments to environments and commands within AuCTeX). Is there a way of unmapping `SPC` in the minibuffer, and remapping it to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem. Just bind `SPC` to `self-insert-command` in the minibuffer keymaps.

There are several such maps, depending on your Emacs version:

```
minibuffer-inactive-mode-map     minibuffer-local-completion-map  
minibuffer-local-filename-completion-map minibuffer-local-filename-must-match-map 
minibuffer-local-isearch-map     minibuffer-local-map             
minibuffer-local-must-match-filename-map minibuffer-local-must-match-map 
minibuffer-local-ns-map          minibuffer-local-shell-command-map
```

But some of them inherit from others, so you can just bind the key in the parents.  Start with **`minibuffer-local-completion-map`**.  Probably that is the only one you need, but if not then try also `minibuffer-local-must-match-map`. Those are the two completion maps.

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map (kbd "SPC") 'self-insert-command)
```

Comment: See also <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-Maps.html>.